# Can't connect to shared local SQL Server database using impersonation

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-7, impersonation, localdb

I'm trying to test connecting to a local SQL Server database using C#. This database has been shared successfully and I can connect to it using multiple users using `SQLCMD`. This includes the desired user, READ.

Now what I'm trying to do is impersonate READ and then connect to the database in C#. I am using the standard impersonation mechanisms that have been shown to work.

When I impersonate READ I get the exception:

Test method

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>   (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Unexpected error occurred inside a LocalDB instance API method call. See the Windows Application event log for error details.)

I have checked and double checked the connection strings. My main user account `ADMIN` (who owns the share) uses the same string to connect to the database just fine.

The exception notes the application event logs will have more information. They only note additionally "`ACCESS IS DENIED`" with error 5.

I have given connect permissions along with execute and others. I've tried giving sysadmin to the entire server to the user account and still, when I impersonate, it can't connect.

Note: For impersonation I am using "Interactive" level impersonation.

Is there something I'm missing? Do I need to give specific permissions to the credential in the local system? Can Localdb just not authenticate properly using native SQL Server clients? Why can I connect when running a process as other users, just not using in-process impersonation?

Comment: And what happens if, after impersonation, you start SqlLocalDB.exe with "info" argument?

Comment: I get a list of names. Two share names and two non-share names (Projects and v11.0, the defaults).

Comment: If anyone is curious, I ended up doing my testing that I was using impersonation for with a process calling SQLCMD. You can then check the standard error output. It's a bit more annoying and doesn't use the code that I'm actually calling, but its sufficient for now. I'm not including it as an answer to my question because it's not an answer. Hopefully this can eventually be actually answered.